# Paste Date to Time in an Irregular Way

Tags: r, plyr, as.date

I am trying to combine times with it's corresponding date, but am having trouble. The dates and times are in one list where the date is followed by times for that date. This papptern continues in an irregular fashion.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
z = as.data.frame(c("2014-12-01", "7:00", "8:00", "9:00"))
z$x = llply(z[[1]], as.Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
names(z) = c("a", "b")
dp = function (x) {x = z$b
                  if(class(x) != "Date") {paste(z$a, x)} else {x = z$b}}
as.data.frame(llply(z, dp))[1]
```

And I get:

```
             a
1 2014-12-01 16405
2          7:00 NA
3          8:00 NA
4          9:00 NA
```

I'm looking for:

```
             a
1 2014-12-01
2          7:00 2014-12-01
3          8:00 2014-12-01
4          9:00 2014-12-01
```

Ideally, i'd like a solution to combine the date and time into a single date-time object.

Please help...thanks

Comment: The desired result still looks like `character` column instead of `date time`.  Also, why you have `row 1` with only `date`?  Is it some kind of identifier?

Comment: Another doubt is whether the time always follow the dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a date-time object

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, as.POSIXct(paste(v1[1], v1[-1]), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'), by=gr]
#    gr                  V1
#1:  1 2014-12-01 07:00:00
#2:  1 2014-12-01 08:00:00
#3:  1 2014-12-01 09:00:00
#4:  2 2014-12-02 06:00:00
#5:  2 2014-12-02 09:00:00
```

Or if you need it to be in the `format` as shown in the result

```
 setDT(df)[, c(v1[1],paste(v1[-1], v1[1])) , by=gr]
 #   gr              V1
 #1:  1      2014-12-01
 #2:  1 7:00 2014-12-01
 #3:  1 8:00 2014-12-01
 #4:  1 9:00 2014-12-01
 #5:  2      2014-12-02
 #6:  2 6:00 2014-12-02
 #7:  2 9:00 2014-12-02
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("2014-12-01", "7:00", "8:00", "9:00", "2014-12-02", "6:00", "9:00")
indx <- grepl('-', v1)
df <- data.frame(v1, gr=cumsum(indx), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```